# How to force panelView to change linewidth, when there is no option in the package?

Tags: r, ggplot2, panel-data

I would like to change some graphical features of a `panelView` plot. In the help menu, I did not find a corresponding option.

I'm not so much into package programming. But I guess they build up on other packages. Perhaps `panelView` uses `ggplot2` or something similar which could be accessed with a workaround? Can I somehow adjust aesthetics?

Here is the MWE from the package. In this case, lines are too thin.

```
library(panelView) 
data(panelView) 
panelView(turnout ~ 1 + policy_mail_in + policy_motor, type="outcome",  
data = turnout, index = c("abb","year"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code for `panelView`, you can see that it hard codes the line width at 0.5. The `panelView` function does nothing too fancy (like require internals), so you could modify the function so that there is a line width argument. A hacky solution but there is it.

I have done so, but the function is >1300 lines of code, so I'm not doing to repost it here. Rather, you can copy from [here](https://github.com/ramorel/grad-school/blob/master/R/panelView_B.R).

Now, using the `panelView_B` function, with the new argument, `line.width`, we can modify the lines:

```
library(panelView) 
data(panelView) 
panelView_B(turnout ~ 1 + policy_mail_in + policy_motor, type="outcome",  
          data = turnout, index = c("abb","year"), line.width = 1)
```

[image]